# Correlate ssGSEA score with Seurat's scaled expression data

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, correlation, gsea

I want to check the correlation between the expression of a given "test_gene"* in each cluster within a scRNA-seq database with the expression of a signature (i.e., gene sets whose expression is known and validated to be a “marker” of a specific phenotype) in a specific cluster, that is:

- Corr.: ssGSEA of signature in cluster X vs test_gene in cluster A
- Corr.: ssGSEA of signature in cluster X vs test_gene in cluster B
- Corr.: ssGSEA of signature in cluster X vs test_gene in cluster C
- and so on...

Since I don't have much experience in transcriptomic data analysis, I was wondering what would be the best method to achieve this. The database I'm using (public) contains data from 19 different samples (patients), so I was thinking of doing a "sample-wise" Spearman's test. See this dummy example to exemplify my point:

|  | test_gene in cluster_A | ssGSEA score of signature in cluster_X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sample_1 | 2.1 | 2.3 |
| Sample_2 | 1.63 | 1.76 |
| Sample_3 | 0.39 | 0.45 |
| . . . | . . . | . . . |
| Sample_19 | 0.95 | 0.81 |

|  | test_gene in cluster_B | ssGSEA score of signature in cluster_X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sample_1 | 1.91 | 1.21 |
| Sample_2 | 0.03 | 1.85 |
| Sample_3 | 3.13 | 0.9 |
| . . . | . . . | . . . |
| Sample_19 | 0.09 | 2.12 |

And so on with clusters C, D, E, etc...

In this example (not real data) you can tell that gene_a's expression in cluster_A looks like could be linearly correlated with the signature's expression in cluster_X (they go "hand in hand"), but the same is not true for cluster_B. Here, a Spearman's test should output a p-value lower than 0.05 (signif.) for "test_gene in cluster_A vs signature_in_X", and higher than 0.05 (not signif.) for "test_gene in cluster_B vs signature_in_X".

All the samples in the actual database are from treatment-naïve renal cell carcinoma (RCC) patients, all of them with the same sub-type. Concerning the test_gene, it is actually a "placeholder" for each of the 20+ genes I want to test for a correlation. The cluster_X here would actually be the malignant cell cluster, being all the other clusters (A, B, etc.) the many cell types in the tumor micro-environment (TME). As for the data points, there would be 19, one per sample, but in the example I only put 3 just to make the point. There is one sample per patient, so sample = patient.

Are there any special considerations (like the type of normalization or data treatment) I should have to achieve this?

*The average of the normalized expression for that gene in all cells from the same cluster and sample.